# I need help with a non-inverting op-amp circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier, ltspice

For an exercise I need to design a non-inverting amplifier circuit, simulate and measure the supply current at V+, and compare it with the datasheets.

The op-amps in use are LT1001 and LT1007. I attached a screenshot of my circuit design in LTspice.

The problem I have is that my measurements are always way off when compared to the datasheet. My measurement of the current at V+ is -0.001283618 fA when used with the LT1001, but it should be close to 1.3 mA.

I'm really stuck and I don't know why my measurements are wrong. Maybe one of you can help me.

[image]

Comment: You have not connected power to the opamp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to connect the nodes of your voltage supplies to those of your amplifier. You can label the top of the voltage source nodes with a v+ and a v- and do the same for the op-amp supply nodes as well.